# Finding parameters in the intersection of two sets

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm having trouble with the following problem. I have two sets $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: 3x+y\le 0 \}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: ax+by < 0 \}$ and I am supposed to find all real parameters $a,b$ such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$. How to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in $A$ are $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $y \leq -3x.$ Therefore, any $(z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $y>-3x$ are not in $A.$

But

$$y>-3x \iff 3x +y > 0 \iff -3x - y < 0.$$

So consider $a = -3$ and $b = -1.$

Next, observe that $y + 3x = 0$ and $ax + by = 0$ are lines that passes at $(0,0).$ So these are the only real values of $a$ and $b$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset.$